# How can I list all method of a class/object?

Tags: jscript, jscript.net

How can I list all available method of a class or object in jscript.net? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

I imagine it is possible to a certain extent. It may require compiling with `/fast-`. Any standard object introspection tool would be a good place to start. Have you got a particular object you're wanting to traverse?

There are lots of good articles on [Javascript Introspection](http://www.syger.it/Tutorials/JavaScriptIntrospector.html) and that's one of them, including [this one on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275351/javascript-reflection).

Answer (score -1):

Your answer is here [LINK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/667a3hk6%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

You can list all available methods of a class or object

Comment: This answer links to an article about JScript.NET which has nothing to do with Javascript.

Comment: @ZippyV Looks like the question has nothing to do with JavaScript : ).

Comment: This is a JScript.NET question

Comment: on further looking into it it doesn't seem so easy. Can you use the expando modifier to hook into JScript and list all classes and objects this way. A hacked solution but it may not be possible. Intrigued